# Reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, parsing

"Reached  end of file while parsing" error is appearing.  I have checked all the braces, but it's still showing me an error. Can someone please let me know where I should add another brace or take one out.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.*;

public class WageComputer { 

    final double HOURLY_WAGE=7.25;
    final double OVERTIME= 1.5*HOURLY_WAGE;

    private int numberOfHours;
    private double totalSales;
    double commision;
    double basicWage;
    double commisionWage;

    public WageComputer() {
        numberOfHours=40;
        totalSales=150.00;
    }


    public WageComputer(int hours, double sales){
        numberOfHours = hours;
        totalSales= sales;
    }

    public int getnumberOfHours() {
        return numberOfHours;
    }

    public double gettotalSales(){
        return totalSales;
    }

    public void setnumberOfHours(int hours) {
        numberOfHours = hours;
    }

    public void settotalSales (double sales) {
        totalSales= sales;
    }

    public double basicWage() {
        double basicWage = HOURLY_WAGE * numberOfHours;

        if (numberOfHours >40){
            basicWage = (numberOfHours - 40) * OVERTIME + 40 * HOURLY_WAGE;
        }
        return basicWage;
    }

    public double commisionWage(){  

        if (totalSales <= 0.99){
            commision = 0;
            return commision * totalSales;
        }
        else if (totalSales <= 99.99){
            commision = .05;
            return commision * totalSales;
        }
        else if (totalSales <= 299.99) {
            commision = .10;
            return commision *totalSales;
        }
        else if (totalSales >= 300.00) {
            commision = .15;
            return commision *totalSales;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indent your code correctly! It makes it easier to find the mistake

Comment: You're missing the class closing brace. If you indented your code correctly and use an IDE it would be easy to see this kind of mistakes.

Comment: Don't waste our time, or your own. Your IDE can do this a lot quicker than we can, and with 100% reliability.

Comment: Then add a return statement if that's the error you're getting

Answer (score 1):

It may look like this.
I update it by my eclipse, wish it could help for you.

```
 public class WageComputer { 

     final double HOURLY_WAGE=7.25;
     final double OVERTIME= 1.5*HOURLY_WAGE;


 private int numberOfHours;
 private double totalSales;
        double commision;
        double basicWage;
        double commisionWage;



     public WageComputer() {
     numberOfHours=40;
     totalSales=150.00;
    }


   public WageComputer(int hours, double sales){
      numberOfHours = hours;
      totalSales= sales;
    }

   public int getnumberOfHours() {
      return numberOfHours;
    }

   public double gettotalSales(){
   return totalSales;
   }

   public void setnumberOfHours(int hours) {
      numberOfHours = hours;
   }

   public void settotalSales (double sales) {
      totalSales= sales;
    }

    public double basicWage() {

         double basicWage = HOURLY_WAGE * numberOfHours;

         if (numberOfHours >40){
            basicWage = (numberOfHours - 40) * OVERTIME + 40 * HOURLY_WAGE;
            }
            return basicWage;
            }

     public double commisionWage(){  
        if (totalSales <= 0.99){
            commision = 0;          
            }
            else if (totalSales <= 99.99){
            commision = .05;         
            }
            else if (totalSales <= 299.99) {
            commision = .10;          
             }
            else if (totalSales >= 300.00) {
            commision = .15;           
            }
        return commision *totalSales;   
     }
     }
```

Comment: Thank You! It compiled just fine.